# Sync android app data between devices using some host

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have a little android app that creates schedules for teams. For instance there is team of 9 and one user creates schedule with names of all members of his team on android device. How can this user share the result with others.

I see this like he uploads serialized schedule data with some id to a server, and others get the data requesting the id.

What technologies or libraries should I use? And is there any free hosts to keep this data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check Firebase by Google. It does what you want (Realtime Database/Data synchronization).

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Definitely I will try to use it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a question which sparks discussion because everyone has a favorite. I started to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/features/) for this after implementing my own databases and servers. Especially for beginners it is very easy to use and has a mighty realtime database. You have to care about a lot less code than you would need if you implement everything by yourself. The security is also a lot better with all the rules you can apply to your data. The documentation is also a big plus. Everything is explained in detail.